# How to get the function name which calls current function?

Tags: c, function

Inside a function, one can put (for gcc)

```
printf("%s: I am here!", __FUNCTION__);
```

to indicate where a particular message comes from. Now, suppose I have serval functions A1, A2, A3,..., which all might call function B(). I am wondering if there is a neat way to indicate which function calls B() at run-time.

Comment: If you want a standard way, pass `__func__` in as an argument. In the case of an extra argument that never changes when you call it, you might find a macro useful for calling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `backtrace()` (which is not completely portable either)

See this link:
http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/backtrace.3.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no portable way to do this. However, if you want to delve into the realm of non-portable hacks, GCC provides `__builtin_return_address()` with which you can get the return address. Subsequently passing that address to `dladdr` (also a nonstandard function, but available on most unix-like systems) will give you the name of the function at the binary level (which might differ from the function at the abstract program level if any sort of inlining, inter-procedural-analysis-based optimization, etc. took place). I would not recommend using these sort of hacks for anything beyond debugging/profiling.

I suspect similar mechanisms exist on other platforms and compilers.